# How to filter Enum type column in Kendo Grid with multi select

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Enum Model called TargetType and ReportViewModel. All the records from the Report table is listing in a kendo grid using the viewmodel ReportViewModel. But the problem is If I try to filter the enum type column 'EmpTypes' it will break the application and cannot filter it. How can I make it filter the column EmpType in Kendo?

```
public enum EmpTypes
{
[Display(Name="Service")
Service = 0,
[Display(Name="Sales")
Sales = 1
[Display(Name="Purchase")
Purchase = 2,
[Display(Name="Office")
Office = 3
}
public class ReportViewModel
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public EmpTypes EmpTypes {get;set;}
}
```

The Report Table consists the following record

```
{Name = "AbC",  EmpTypes = 1},
{Name = "xyz",  EmpTypes = 2},
```

In ReportController GetEmpTypes() , I am fetching the data into Kendo

```
IQueryable<Report> reportquery = dbContext.Reports;
var kendoList = reportquery.Select(r=>new ReportViewModel()
{
Name = r.Name,
EmpTypes = r.EmpTypes
});
return kendolist.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request);
```

In Kendo Grid

.

```
Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Report Name");
    columns.Bound(c => c.EmpTypes).Title("Type")
        .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Multi(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetEmpTypes", "Report"))
            )
        );
})
```